# Managing multiple linux\freebsd server?

Tags: linux, freebsd, puppet, configuration-management

I currently have 5 FreeBSD servers that I'm handling on my own.

I just bought 10 more servers and I want to start using some centralized configuration system like Puppet.

I was wondering if there are any other alternatives to puppet? Are there any downsides to it?

Comment: Our very own @Voretaq7 is the port maintainer for `radmin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/)

[Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/)

[CFengine](http://cfengine.com/)

[Ansible](http://ansible.cc/)

[bcfg2](https://trac.mcs.anl.gov/projects/bcfg2)

[R?ex](http://rexify.org/)

[Others:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open_source_configuration_management_software)

I've only ever used Puppet and a little bit of chef.  They're all about the same really.

Puppet has a few downsides, but so do all the others.  Puppet and chef both have a HUGE community, both [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/puppet), and on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/puppet), and also on [other](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/) sites (but who'd go to those, eh?)

YMMV.